# How to pass my defined lists from main() function to all other functions?

Tags: python-3.x

```
#Project #3 Water Quality
#Project Template
def GetChoice():
#local variables
    user_choice = str()
#Display menu and get choice
    print()
    print("Select one of the options listed below:  ")
    print("\tP\t==\tPrint Data")
    print("\tA\t==\tGet Averages")
    print("\tAZ\t==\tAverage Per Zone")
    print("\tAL\t==\tAbove Levels by Zone")
    print("\tBL\t==\tBelow Levels")
    print("\tQ\t==\tQuit")
    print()
    while True:
        try:
            #Get choice
            user_choice = input("Enter choice:  ")
            print()
            user_choice = user_choice.upper()
            #Depending on input, print items from menu
            if user_choice == 'P':
                PrintData()
                GetChoice()
            elif user_choice == 'A':
                Average()
                GetChoice()
            elif user_choice == 'AZ':
                AverageZones()
                GetChoice()
            elif user_choice == 'AL':
                AboveLevels()
                GetChoice()
            elif user_choice == 'BL':
                BelowLevels()
                GetChoice()
            elif user_choice == 'Q':
                break
            #Wrong input gets exception error and message error
            else:
                print('Invalid choice. Enter P, A, AZ, AL, BL, or Q to Quit')
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid choice. Enter P, A, AZ, AL, BL, or Q to Quit')
    exit


    return user_choice

#enter the rest of your functions here.

def PrintData(zones):
    zones = ["North 1", "North 2", "North 3", "North 4", "East 1 ", "East 2 ", "East 3 ", "East 4 ", "West 1 ", "West 2 ", "West 3 ", "West 4 ", "South 1", "South 2", "South 3", "South 4"]
    lead = [10, 13, 5, 16, 17, 8, 3, 2, 6, 9, 11, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5]
    copper = [0.03, 0.25, 1.4, 0.15, 0.37, 0.85, 1.5, 0.99, 0.55, 1.1, 0.97, 0.77, 0.82, 0.74, 0.96, 1.1]
    #Header
    print('Lead and Copper Water Study')
    print()
    print('Zone\t\tLead\tCopper')
    print('****************************************')
    #Each zone with correct lead (ppb) and copper (ppm) values
    print(zones[0],'\t',lead[0],'\t',copper[0])
    print(zones[1],'\t',lead[1],'\t',copper[1])
    print(zones[2],'\t',lead[2],'\t',copper[2])
    print(zones[3],'\t',lead[3],'\t',copper[3])
    print(zones[4],'\t',lead[4],'\t',copper[4])
    print(zones[5],'\t',lead[5],'\t',copper[5])
    print(zones[6],'\t',lead[6],'\t',copper[6])
    print(zones[7],'\t',lead[7],'\t',copper[7])
    print(zones[8],'\t',lead[8],'\t',copper[8])
    print(zones[9],'\t',lead[9],'\t',copper[9])
    print(zones[10],'\t',lead[10],'\t',copper[10])
    print(zones[11],'\t',lead[11],'\t',copper[11])
    print(zones[12],'\t',lead[12],'\t',copper[12])
    print(zones[13],'\t',lead[13],'\t',copper[13])
    print(zones[14],'\t',lead[14],'\t',copper[14])
    print(zones[15],'\t',lead[15],'\t',copper[15])

def Average():
    lead = [10, 13, 5, 16, 17, 8, 3, 2, 6, 9, 11, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5]
    copper = [0.03, 0.25, 1.4, 0.15, 0.37, 0.85, 1.5, 0.99, 0.55, 1.1, 0.97, 0.77, 0.82, 0.74, 0.96, 1.1]
    #Average Calculation formulas
    LeadAverage = sum(lead) / len(lead)
    CopperAverage = sum(copper) / len(copper)
    #Header
    print('Average Levels of Lead and Copper')
    print('*********************************')
    #Format to 2 decimals
    print('Lead Average:\t', format(LeadAverage, ',.2f'))
    print('Copper Average:\t', format(CopperAverage, ',.2f'))

def AverageZones():
    lead = [10, 13, 5, 16, 17, 8, 3, 2, 6, 9, 11, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5]
    copper = [0.03, 0.25, 1.4, 0.15, 0.37, 0.85, 1.5, 0.99, 0.55, 1.1, 0.97, 0.77, 0.82, 0.74, 0.96, 1.1]
    #Puts lead in their proper zones
    NorthLeadZone = [lead[0], lead[1], lead[2], lead[3]]
    EastLeadZone = [lead[4], lead[5], lead[6], lead[7]]
    WestLeadZone = [lead[8], lead[9], lead[10], lead[11]]
    SouthLeadZone = [lead[12], lead[13], lead[14], lead[15]]
    #Puts copper in their proper zones
    NorthCopperZone = [copper[0], copper[1], copper[2], copper[3]]
    EastCopperZone = [copper[4], copper[5], copper[6], copper[7]]
    WestCopperZone = [copper[8], copper[9], copper[10], copper[11]]
    SouthCopperZone = [copper[12], copper[13], copper[14], copper[15]]
    #Takes the lead zones to find the average in this formula
    NorthLeadAverage = sum(NorthLeadZone) / len(NorthLeadZone)
    EastLeadAverage = sum(EastLeadZone) / len(EastLeadZone)
    WestLeadAverage = sum(WestLeadZone) / len(WestLeadZone)
    SouthLeadAverage = sum(SouthLeadZone) / len(SouthLeadZone)
    #Takes the copper zones to find the average in this formula
    NorthCopperAverage = sum(NorthCopperZone) / len(NorthCopperZone)
    EastCopperAverage = sum(EastCopperZone) / len(EastCopperZone)
    WestCopperAverage = sum(WestCopperZone) / len(WestCopperZone)
    SouthCopperAverage = sum(SouthCopperZone) / len(SouthCopperZone)
    #Header
    print('Average Values by Zone')
    print('**********************')
    print('Lead Averages by Zone')
    print('************************')
    #Lead averages put into 2 decimals
    print('North\t', format(NorthLeadAverage, ',.2f'))
    print('East\t', format(EastLeadAverage, ',.2f'))
    print('West\t', format(WestLeadAverage, ',.2f'))
    print('South\t', format(SouthLeadAverage, ',.2f'))
    #Header
    print('Copper Averages by Zone')
    print('************************')
    #Copper averages put into 2 decimals
    print('North\t', format(NorthCopperAverage, ',.2f'))
    print('East\t', format(EastCopperAverage, ',.2f'))
    print('West\t', format(WestCopperAverage, ',.2f'))
    print('South\t', format(SouthCopperAverage, ',.2f'))

def AboveLevels():
    zones = ["North 1", "North 2", "North 3", "North 4", "East 1 ", "East 2 ", "East 3 ", "East 4 ", "West 1 ", "West 2 ", "West 3 ", "West 4 ", "South 1", "South 2", "South 3", "South 4"]
    lead = [10, 13, 5, 16, 17, 8, 3, 2, 6, 9, 11, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5]
    copper = [0.03, 0.25, 1.4, 0.15, 0.37, 0.85, 1.5, 0.99, 0.55, 1.1, 0.97, 0.77, 0.82, 0.74, 0.96, 1.1]
    #Header
    print('Zones Above Safe Levels')
    print('***********************')
    print()
    #Sub-Header
    print('Lead Zones Above Acceptable Levels')
    print('*****************************')
    #If statement formula for any lead above acceptable ppb levels
    if lead[0] > 15:
        print(zones[0], '\t', lead[0])
    if lead[1] > 15:
        print(zones[1], '\t', lead[1])
    if lead[2] > 15:
        print(zones[2], '\t', lead[2])
    if lead[3] > 15:
        print(zones[3], '\t', lead[3])
    if lead[4] > 15:
        print(zones[4], '\t', lead[4])
    if lead[5] > 15:
        print(zones[5], '\t', lead[5])
    if lead[6] > 15:
        print(zones[6], '\t', lead[6])
    if lead[7] > 15:
        print(zones[7], '\t', lead[7])
    if lead[8] > 15:
        print(zones[8], '\t', lead[8])
    if lead[9] > 15:
        print(zones[9], '\t', lead[9])
    if lead[10] > 15:
        print(zones[10], '\t', lead[110])
    if lead[11] > 15:
        print(zones[11], '\t', lead[11])
    if lead[12] > 15:
        print(zones[12], '\t', lead[12])
    if lead[13] > 15:
        print(zones[13], '\t', lead[13])
    if lead[14] > 15:
        print(zones[14], '\t', lead[14])
    if lead[15] > 15:
        print(zones[15], '\t', lead[15])
    #Sub-Header
    print()
    print('Copper Zones Above Acceptable Levels')
    print('*****************************')
    #If statement formula for any copper above acceptable ppm levels
    if copper[0] > 1.3:
        print(zones[0], '\t', copper[0])
    if copper[1] > 1.3:
        print(zones[1], '\t', copper[1])
    if copper[2] > 1.3:
        print(zones[2], '\t', copper[2])
    if copper[3] > 1.3:
        print(zones[3], '\t', copper[3])
    if copper[4] > 1.3:
        print(zones[4], '\t', copper[4])
    if copper[5] > 1.3:
        print(zones[5], '\t', copper[5])
    if copper[6] > 1.3:
        print(zones[6], '\t', copper[6])
    if copper[7] > 1.3:
        print(zones[7], '\t', copper[7])
    if copper[8] > 1.3:
        print(zones[8], '\t', copper[8])
    if copper[9] > 1.3:
        print(zones[9], '\t', copper[9])
    if copper[10] > 1.3:
        print(zones[10], '\t', copper[10])
    if copper[11] > 1.3:
        print(zones[11], '\t', copper[11])
    if copper[12] > 1.3:
        print(zones[12], '\t', copper[12])
    if copper[13] > 1.3:
        print(zones[13], '\t', copper[13])
    if copper[14] > 1.3:
        print(zones[14], '\t', copper[14])
    if copper[15] > 1.3:
        print(zones[15], '\t', copper[15])

def BelowLevels():
    zones = ["North 1", "North 2", "North 3", "North 4", "East 1 ", "East 2 ", "East 3 ", "East 4 ", "West 1 ", "West 2 ", "West 3 ", "West 4 ", "South 1", "South 2", "South 3", "South 4"]
    lead = [10, 13, 5, 16, 17, 8, 3, 2, 6, 9, 11, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5]
    copper = [0.03, 0.25, 1.4, 0.15, 0.37, 0.85, 1.5, 0.99, 0.55, 1.1, 0.97, 0.77, 0.82, 0.74, 0.96, 1.1]
    #Header
    print('Zones Below Safe Levels')
    print('***********************')
    print()
    #Sub-Header
    print('Lead Zones Below Acceptable Levels')
    print('*****************************')
    #If statement formula for any lead below acceptable ppb levels
    if lead[0] < 15:
        print(zones[0], '\t', lead[0])
    if lead[1] < 15:
        print(zones[1], '\t', lead[1])
    if lead[2] < 15:
        print(zones[2], '\t', lead[2])
    if lead[3] < 15:
        print(zones[3], '\t', lead[3])
    if lead[4] < 15:
        print(zones[4], '\t', lead[4])
    if lead[5] < 15:
        print(zones[5], '\t', lead[5])
    if lead[6] < 15:
        print(zones[6], '\t', lead[6])
    if lead[7] < 15:
        print(zones[7], '\t', lead[7])
    if lead[8] < 15:
        print(zones[8], '\t', lead[8])
    if lead[9] < 15:
        print(zones[9], '\t', lead[9])
    if lead[10] < 15:
        print(zones[10], '\t', lead[10])
    if lead[11] < 15:
        print(zones[11], '\t', lead[11])
    if lead[12] < 15:
        print(zones[12], '\t', lead[12])
    if lead[13] < 15:
        print(zones[13], '\t', lead[13])
    if lead[14] < 15:
        print(zones[14], '\t', lead[14])
    if lead[15] < 15:
        print(zones[15], '\t', lead[15])
    #Sub-header
    print()
    print('Copper Zones Below Acceptable Levels')
    print('*****************************')
    #If statement formula for any copper below acceptable ppm levels
    if copper[0] < 1.3:
        print(zones[0], '\t', copper[0])
    if copper[1] < 1.3:
        print(zones[1], '\t', copper[1])
    if copper[2] < 1.3:
        print(zones[2], '\t', copper[2])
    if copper[3] < 1.3:
        print(zones[3], '\t', copper[3])
    if copper[4] < 1.3:
        print(zones[4], '\t', copper[4])
    if copper[5] < 1.3:
        print(zones[5], '\t', copper[5])
    if copper[6] < 1.3:
        print(zones[6], '\t', copper[6])
    if copper[7] < 1.3:
        print(zones[7], '\t', copper[7])
    if copper[8] < 1.3:
        print(zones[8], '\t', copper[8])
    if copper[9] < 1.3:
        print(zones[9], '\t', copper[9])
    if copper[10] < 1.3:
        print(zones[10], '\t', copper[10])
    if copper[11] < 1.3:
        print(zones[11], '\t', copper[11])
    if copper[12] < 1.3:
        print(zones[12], '\t', copper[12])
    if copper[13] < 1.3:
        print(zones[13], '\t', copper[13])
    if copper[14] < 1.3:
        print(zones[14], '\t', copper[14])
    if copper[15] < 1.3:
        print(zones[15], '\t', copper[15])

def main():
#main variables.  Do not change these
    GetChoice()
    zones = ["North 1", "North 2", "North 3", "North 4", "East 1 ", "East 2 ", "East 3 ", "East 4 ", "West 1 ", "West 2 ", "West 3 ", "West 4 ", "South 1", "South 2", "South 3", "South 4"]
    lead = [10, 13, 5, 16, 17, 8, 3, 2, 6, 9, 11, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5] 
    copper = [0.03, 0.25, 1.4, 0.15, 0.37, 0.85, 1.5, 0.99, 0.55, 1.1, 0.97, 0.77, 0.82, 0.74, 0.96, 1.1]
    choice = str()

main()
```

I cannot go through use of global variables or splicing lists. My problem is that I cannot repeat my lists in all functions, and have to find a way through parameters and arguments to make sure my lists from main() pass through all my other functions. Any help on this would be very much appreciated thank you!

Comment: What is stopping you from passing the lists as parameters?

Comment: I don't know how exactly to do that.... that is my problem

Comment: All you have to do is `GetChoice(zones)` to pass `zones` to `GetChoice()`. You should really spend more time learning python.